# Python Django - render OrderedDict in view like json

Tags: python, django

I'm new in Django and Python.

I'm in **HTML** printing data from python using

```
{{ body.example }}
```

Some data is render ok in plain text, but there one that is printing like this:

```
[OrderedDict([(u'value', u'5650.00'), (u'operation_number', 130990), (u'comments', u'TESTE'), (u'date', OrderedDict([(u'start', 20160519), (u'end', 20160519)]))])]
```

How can I render this type of data like json(becouse the result from api is json):

```
{
                      "value": "5650.00",
                      "operation_number": "130990",
                      "comments": "TESTE",
                      "date": {
                        "start": "20160519",
                        "end": "20160519"
                      }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done the same in one of my projects - [upvote_system](https://github.com/pankajsinghal/upvote_system). You can refer the same. Basically, You will have to create a parser/filter yourself - Follow this [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/) from django.

Create a file called `tojson.py` with the following content[(ref from project)](https://github.com/pankajsinghal/upvote_system/blob/c62d3cb6c2390ed5e6be768c521d7b27a4c4ed78/mysite/votes/templatetags/tojson.py):

```
from django import template
import json
register = template.Library()


@register.filter(is_safe=True)
def tojson(value):
        return byteify(json.loads(json.dumps(value)))

def byteify(input):
    if isinstance(input, dict):
        return {byteify(key):byteify(value) for key,value in input.iteritems()}
    elif isinstance(input, list):
        return [byteify(element) for element in input]
    elif isinstance(input, unicode):
        return input.encode('utf-8')
    else:
        return input
```

load the parser in the html file like this - `{% load tojson%}`
and then try something like this:

```
your_result_as_json_object = {{your_result|tojson|safe}}
```

You can now use `your_result_as_json_object` as a json/dict & operate on it.

Comment: First, thanks for try help. I create this file and put this code {% load tojson%} in top of my HTML, and there a erro: TemplateSyntaxError at /docs
'tojson' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify

Comment: can I put this file tojson.py in any place?

Comment: No. Create a `dir` called `templatetags` and put the file inside that. Follow this [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/) - update in the answer also

Comment: Already have this folder then I put there, but the erros is the same: 'tojson' is not a registered tag library

Comment: did you load it like this `{% load tojson%}` & restarted your server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164361/discussion-between-willians-martins-and-pankaj-singhal).

Comment: yes it works, but when there is an object with value 'null' like:
{ "value": null }
the output is:
{ "value": None }
And None is a JS error

Comment: {{your_result|tojson|safe}} is a perfect way to have your site hacked, don't do this. What do you think gets rendered when one of those JSON fields comes back as "</script><script src="https://hack-my-site.com/nukeme.js"></script>"?

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to define your own custom tag or filter as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags). And create something like this:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('result.html')
def display(json_obj):
    json_data = json.loads(json_obj)
    context = {}
    for obj in json_data:
       # Process data and save to context dictionary
       ... 

    # Return context
    return {'context':context}
```

result.html:
For example if you want to show it in table row format it will look something like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>context.value</td>
  <td>context.operation_number</td>
  <td>context.comments</td>
  <td>context.date.start</td>
  <td>context.date.end</td>
</tr>
```

Not sure if it suitable for your scenario but custom tag will allow to display json object in different formats.